# Unity Serialization depth warnings

Tags: unity, c#

I've got this class to store spells for my game

```cs
[Serializable]
public class Spell
{
    public SpellComponents component;
    public SpellSequence sequence;
    public float delay;
    public Vector3 offset;
    
    public List<Spell> next = new List<Spell>();
    
}
```

but always get warnings like this

```
Serialization depth limit 7 exceeded at 'Magic.SpellSystem::Spell.next'. There may be an object composition cycle in one or more of your serialized classes.
```

Spells are made in a node based editor and can branch off like this
[image: A Spell in the Editor]

How can i fix this?

Comment: [Unity's documentation includes an example of how to serialize a tree structure safely](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization-Custom.html).

Comment: how can I make the Spell class always use a custom serialization?

Comment: By writing your custom serialization code as demonstrated in that document. If you run into any trouble with this, please edit your question to show what you've tried and what's going wrong.

Comment: So i can just use Spell anywhere and it automatically gets replaced with the serialised version for serialization?

Comment: I can't make any guarantee stronger than "if you write the correct code, the correct thing will happen." If you find you're not getting the correct outcome, then your code for that case is incorrect, and you should show it to us in your question so we can help you fix it.

Comment: An alternative is to have Spell extends from ScriptableObject, and make all the necessary changes for that to be supported. It’s a bit of a big step though. Is that something you would consider?